# How do I initialize a partial view so that getting different info shows the PartialViewResult containing the new info?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I have the following scenario:

I have a strongly typed partial view that display info for a view model called PlaceVieWModel it is rendered inside a strongly typed view for MainPlaceViewModel.

Classes:

```
public class PlaceViewModel
{
    public int PlaceID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    public bool HasLiveMusic { get; set; }
}

public class MainPlaceViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<PlaceViewModel> Places { get; set; }
    public string WebPage { get; set; }
    public string LogoRoute { get; set; }
    public string LogoDetailCssClass { get; set; }
}
```

In the MainPlaceModelView view I generate an Ajax.ActionLink for each of the MainPlaceViewModel.Places that gets the info for that Place and displays it in the partial view, this is the code for that:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Places)
{                 
     @Ajax.ActionLink(item.Name, "", "", new AjaxOptions { Url = Url.Action("GetPlaceInfo", "MainPlaces", new { placeId = item.PlaceID }), HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "placeInfo", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "loading" })                                              
 }
```

This is the action:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPlaceInfo(int placeID)
{
     var place = _db.Places.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PlaceID == placeID);

     PlaceViewModel placeViewModel = new PlaceViewModel();

     placeViewModel.Address = place.Address;
     placeViewModel.HasLiveMusic = place.HasLiveMusic;
     placeViewModel.Latitude = place.Latitude;
     placeViewModel.Longitude = place.Longitude;
     placeViewModel.Name = place.Name;
     placeViewModel.PlaceID = place.PlaceID;

     return PartialView("_PlaceInfo", placeViewModel);
  }
```

My problem is how should I initialize the @Html.Partial, if i do it like this:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
     Loading...
</div>
<div id="palceInfo">
     @Html.Partial("_PlaceInfo", Model.Places.FirstOrDefault())
</div>
```

The partial view always shows the first item no matter which Ajax.ActionLink is pressed.

Any idea on how can I initialize it so that it also works when any of the ActionLinks is pressed?

**UPDATE:** The problem was a typo on my target div, the id was "palceInfo" and I´m setting the action link to update a "placeInfo", I can´t believe I lost so much time because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that GetPlaceInfo(int placeID) action works right (returns proper data), I do not see other errors besides possibly one.

UpdateTargetId on your action link is equal to "placeInfo". From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.updatetargetid.aspx): UpdateTargetId  Gets or sets the ID of the DOM element to update by using the response from the server.

You did not show your view in full, but I think that you are missing an element there with id="placeInfo". If this is the case, ajax simply does not have an element where it wants to put the result. Try placing your partial into a div with such id:

```
<div id="placeInfo">
    @Html.Partial("_PlaceInfo", Model.Places.FirstOrDefault())
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
@Html.Partial() runs only one time - when your page loads first time. If it gets you right data first time, you should not need to mess with it anymore. The div that contains that partial will get updated when you call your GetPlaceInfo method through an action link. So there are two places to check: your GetPlacesInfo action and the ActionLink.

First, check GetPlacesInfo. Put a break point on it, pass different ids to it and make sure you get right results.

Second, I do not use MS Ajax extensions (I do something different for my ajax calls), but try this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.Name, "GetPlaceInfo", "MainPlaces", new { placeId = item.PlaceID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeInfo", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "loading" })
```

Assuming "MainPlaces" is the controller name

Comment: That's exactly how I have my view right now and its not working.